# Embed simple external application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, tcp

```js
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample
{
   private static void Main()
   {
      using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
      {
         Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
         ConfigurationSection sitesSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites");
         ConfigurationElementCollection sitesCollection = sitesSection.GetCollection();
         ConfigurationElement siteElement = FindElement(sitesCollection, "site", "name", @"Contoso");

         if (siteElement == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not found!");

         ConfigurationElementCollection siteCollection = siteElement.GetCollection();
         ConfigurationElement applicationElement = siteCollection.CreateElement("application");

         applicationElement["path"] = @"/ShoppingCart";
         ConfigurationElementCollection applicationCollection = applicationElement.GetCollection();
         ConfigurationElement virtualDirectoryElement = applicationCollection.CreateElement("virtualDirectory");
         virtualDirectoryElement["path"] = @"/";
         virtualDirectoryElement["physicalPath"] = @"C:\Inetpub\Contoso\ShoppingCart";
         applicationCollection.Add(virtualDirectoryElement);
         siteCollection.Add(applicationElement);

         serverManager.CommitChanges();
      }
   }

   private static ConfigurationElement FindElement(ConfigurationElementCollection collection, string elementTagName, params string[] keyValues)
   {
      foreach (ConfigurationElement element in collection)
      {
         if (String.Equals(element.ElementTagName, elementTagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         {
            bool matches = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i += 2)
            {
               object o = element.GetAttributeValue(keyValues[i]);
               string value = null;
               if (o != null)
               {
                  value = o.ToString();
               }
               if (!String.Equals(value, keyValues[i + 1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
               {
                  matches = false;
                  break;
               }
            }
            if (matches)
            {
               return element;
            }
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

My angular client works with IIS. All GET requests are well served by IIS.
Every http POST request should be converted to TCP request that will be sent to another PC.

Should I create an ASP.net application for this purpose ?
Can I use another architecture(but ASP.net) that will work with IIS ?

This external application has no GUI. Only simple console (which is not mandatory).

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Without more details or a concrete example it is difficult for others to know what  you meant by "Every http POST request should be converted to TCP request that will be sent to another PC". But in most cases you need something upon IIS to translate HTTP POST requests to other things you need (TCP requests or anything else), but ASP.NET is not the only option. You can use other web stacks that IIS supports (classic ASP/PHP/Node.js and more), or simply your own IIS module (native or managed).

Comment: I added a sample code from MS docs.  In this application, how can I get access to incoming HTTP request ?

Comment: What you posted is completely irrelevant (for IIS configuration management, not HTTP request processing). Like I said, you need a web stack upon IIS, or IIS modules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/smooth-streaming-client/web-server-development-reference

Comment: Hi Lex. Thank you very much ! I found a C++ example in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/smooth-streaming-client/walkthrough-creating-a-hosted-web-core-application. Do you think it's possible also with C# ?

Comment: You keep finding the toughest route, so I wonder what keywords you used. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net

Comment: It is difficult to analyse your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.